# Одна база Mysql на несколько сайтов или 1 сайт 1 база?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, оптимизация, производительность

Скажите как будет лучше в плане быстродействия и оптимизации. 
1. Несколько сайтов на одной Mysql базе, у каждого сайта свои таблицы и т.п. 
2. Для каждого сайта своя Mysql база. 
Как лучше?

Comment: "сайты" друг с другом как-нибудь связаны?

Comment: нет, не связаны

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По быстродействию, если вы не используете общие таблицы - разницы почти нет. У вас файлы с мета-информацией, табличным пространством, если разделено, просто хранятся не в общей папке, а в разных. Однако, в плане удобства разработки, управления правами доступа, обслуживанию - лучше для каждого сайта использовать свою базу данных.

И лучше никогда не строить несколько сайтов на одной общей базе с общими таблицами. На первый взгляд это кажется замечательной идеей, однако, на практике поддержка таких систем превращается в ад и оборачивается потерей быстродействия, ради корректного обслуживания обоих/нескольких сайтов, так как требования к ним неминуемо расходятся со временем. Связанность на уровне базы данных будет сильно мешать.